# Use same registered users in new Firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase project where I let users register using mail/password. Now I want to create a new project but letting the users who already got an account in the other project access to this new one project.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, it's sufficient to have all your app's resources provided by a single project, but there are times when you want a single app to be able to access data from multiple projects. And yes, it's possible, Firebase can provide this feature. Because those users belong to differents accounts, you need to use 2 different JSON files.

I recomand you reading this [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html) for a better understanding.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have chosen the email/password option to let users create an account not via their Google account as in that post.

Comment: It's the same thing. In other words, what you are looking for, is permitted with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Firebase command-line tools you could:

- [export the users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport) from the first project
- [import the users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authimport) into the second project

This is a bit involved, so I'd recommend only doing this if you're certain you can't use a single project for both apps.